# Safety of Class.forName in java

Tags: java, security, reflection

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class ForNameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, SecurityException {
        final String s = "java.lang.Integer";
        Object test = Class.forName(s).getConstructors()[0].newInstance(222);
        System.err.println(test);
    }
}
```

In this code I make an object from the String s whose value is known at compile time, so I believe this code is guaranteed to be free from exploits.  Is there any value that "s" could take that would execute arbitrary code?  "s" can contain the code that is desired, if desired.

Comment: You're asking if *"Java injection"* is possible. It's strongly typed (i.e. the parameter **is** a `String` and not a statement). I don't see how this could be possible.

Comment: That code is likely to fail with `IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`, because you have no idea what the first constructor in the array will be. If you want to call the `Integer(int value)` constructor, you should call `Class.forName(s).getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(222);`

Comment: *"Is there any value that "s" could take that would execute arbitrary code?"* No, not *arbitrary* code. However, there could be a class with a matching constructor that does something you don't want to happen, so you're not guaranteed to be safe from bad sideeffects.

Answer (score 0):

One can probably modify the .class file to replace string `"java.lang.Integer"` in string pool with `"com.something.MaliciousClass"`. This class will be loaded and its static initializer will be executed. Even if the constructor parameters **do not** match.

But if one can modify .class file, then any kind of malicious code can be put in there, there is no point in replacing just one String.

If your string is assigned at compile time, you're probably safe, if you read it from somewhere, make sure it contains what you expect, i.e. whitelist names of classes that can be instantiated.